# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, md5

I am writing a program to upload a file and to encode it with md5. I am getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

What am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function handleFiles() {
    var md5;
    files=document.forms["myform"]["files"].value;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        md5 = binl_md5(reader.result, reader.result.length);
        console.log("MD5 is " + md5);
    };
    reader.onerror = function() {
        console.error("Could not read the file");
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);    
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files">
    <input type="submit" value="upload" onclick="handleFiles()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
files=document.forms["myform"]["files"].files;
```

Comment: Consider adding a reference to the object type so that it becomes obvious why using the `files` attribute is the correct way of obtaining the list of files.